# Pywinauto ValueError

Tags: python, debugging, pywinauto

I have several python scripts that run using pywinauto. Everything was going great until this morning where I now have this same error on all of them. Is this a pywinauto bug or have I made a mistake somewhere.

```
23:54:14   File "C:\jenkins_workspace\workspace\regression neo sl110\utilities\regression\Regression.py", line 141, in <module>
23:54:14     run_pgm(args.program, abspath_cfg, abspath_pgm, abspath_output, args.test)
23:54:14   File "C:\jenkins_workspace\workspace\regression neo sl110\utilities\regression\Regression.py", line 98, in run_pgm
23:54:14     result = Auto_Regression.pgm_manage(app, output)
23:54:14   File "C:\jenkins_workspace\workspace\regression neo sl110\utilities\regression\Auto_Regression.py", line 145, in pgm_manage
23:54:14     app.AquisitionError.OK.Click()
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 229, in __getattr__
23:54:14     ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 792, in _resolve_control
23:54:14     criteria)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 339, in WaitUntilPasses
23:54:14     func_val = func(*args)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 558, in _get_ctrl
23:54:14     findwindows.find_window(**criteria[0]))
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 60, in find_window
23:54:14     windows = find_windows(**kwargs)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 204, in find_windows
23:54:14     best_match, wrapped_wins)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 457, in find_best_control_matches
23:54:14     name_control_map = build_unique_dict(controls)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 435, in build_unique_dict
23:54:14     ctrl_names = get_control_names(ctrl, controls)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 292, in get_control_names
23:54:14     non_text_names = GetNonTextControlName(control, allcontrols)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 207, in GetNonTextControlName
23:54:14     if ctrl_.IsVisible() and ctrl_.WindowText() and ctrl_.can_be_label]
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 262, in WindowText
23:54:14     return handleprops.text(self)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py", line 58, in text
23:54:14     buffer_ = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length)
23:54:14   File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 310, in create_unicode_buffer
23:54:14     buftype = c_wchar * init
23:54:14 ValueError: Array length must be >= 0, not -1067052991
```

Comment: I really don't get this. I have logged in and have run the script again and this time it runs successfully. The prevoius runs where it failed I was logged in, however, was not on the gui (I had the screen locked). Now when I run it, even though I am not on the gui, it works. Does anyone have a clue why this would happen???

Comment: Do you use some kind of RDP sessions?

Comment: I sometimes use it. Will that cause this sort of error?? I haven't seen it on any of the other scripts that I have run!

Comment: Yes, it can be a cause. When you close a RDP connection with pywinauto script it can fail. Actually Windows does not draw windows & controls in this case. But it can continue to work if you do not close but minimize RDP client.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of pywinauto's committers and ran into the same problem; I uploaded a new version (0.4.2) of pywinauto that should fix this problem to [our home page](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).